# if(isset($_POST("submit"))) will not work unless i name the submit = "submit"

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I am attempting to use `if(isset($_POST("submitform2")))` however it will not work and only `if(isset($_POST("submit")))` works and I do not understand how to fix it because i have 2 forms in my page

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                        { 

                            echo 'Would you like a hamburger 2';

                            <p>

                                <input type = 'radio' name = 'hamburger' value "yes">yes <p>
                                <input type = 'radio' name = 'hamburger 'value "no"> no<p>
                            </p>

                            <p><input type="submit"  value="submitform2" name ="submitform2" /></p> 
                            <?php
                           }

                        if(isset($_POST["submitform2"]))
                        {
                            $hamburger = $_POST['hamburger'];

                            if($hamburger == 'yes')
                            {
                            }
                                ?>
                                <p><input type="submit"  value="submitThirdForm" name ="submitThirdForm" /></p>

                                <?php
                            }
```

Comment: You'll need to put the html code of the form to know how the first  submit button is declared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using a hidden type with `name = "submit"` will solve your issue, use the below code, put that hidden type in both the forms:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                        { 

                            echo 'Would you like a hamburger 2';

                            <p>

                                <input type = 'radio' name = 'hamburger' value "yes">yes <p>
                                <input type = 'radio' name = 'hamburger 'value "no"> no<p>
                            </p>

                            <p>
                            <input type = "hidden" name = "submit" value = "2" />
                            <input type="submit"  value="submitform2" name ="submitform2" /></p> 
                            <?php
                           }

                        if(isset($_POST["submitform2"]))
                        {
                            $hamburger = $_POST['hamburger'];

                            if($hamburger == 'yes')
                            {
                            }
                                ?>
                                <p>
                                <input type = "hidden" name = "submit" value = "3" />
                                <input type="submit"  value="submitThirdForm" name ="submitThirdForm" /></p>

                                <?php
                            }
```

Comment: but it is still coming up as false it isn't submitted?

Comment: can you tell me what is coming false?

Comment: if(isset($_POST["submitform2"])) is coming out false and  going to the else statement  but they are the same name and they are submitting so i do not understand why

Comment: check once that are you submiting the form with the submit button `name =submitform2`

Comment: I am pressing submit for the form submit2

Comment: check your form and put `method = "post"` if it is not for submitform2  button

Comment: I just tried that and it didn't work

Comment: because it fixed the original problem

Answer (score 1):

This mean you have already an `input name="submit"` before the post and inside the previous form.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

You have 2 inputs named "hamburger"; maybe "hamburger[]" could work better.

```
<input type='radio' name='hamburger[]' value="yes">yes 
<input type='radio' name='hamburger[]' value="no"> no
```

Comment: If you have a `radio` input, then you need to give each option the same name, so the browser knows to group them together.

Answer (score 0):

I too was having some issues with multiple submit buttons to submit forms within the same area.

I assume you have everything correctly nested within  tags, if not that is your first issue. I make this assumption because you haven't posted any HTML code to show a form being present.

Perhaps the use of `if($_POST['submitform2'] == "submitform2"){` would be more useful than isset? This is what ended up resolving my issue.

You are welcome to read more here; where I too asked for assistance.
[Determining Button used to Submit with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30351028/determining-button-used-to-submit-with-php)