# How to distinguish which button was clicked in the html form and based on that pass different values with ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have the following html form:

```
<form class="center" id="myform">
<p>
    <input id="email" name="email" type="email" class="textox email" title="" placeholder="your@email.com" required>
</p>
    <textarea name="slogan" id="textarea" maxlength="140" style="resize:none" class="textoxarea" title="Please enter at least 5 characters" placeholder="Placeholder" ></textarea>
<div class="terms">
        <input type="checkbox" class="required" value="None" id="terms" name="terms">I accept terms</input>
    </div>
</p>
<input type="submit" id="sendfeedback" value="now" disabled/>
    <input id="datetimepicker" type="text" readonly="readonly">
        <input type="submit" id="postmelater" value="send" disabled/>
</form>
```

And as you can see above, I have a form with two buttons. The logic behind it works like that, that when I want to put text to database with current timestamp - I choose button sendfeedback. However, there's also a possibility of adding the feedback with chosen timestamp, that is happening when user choses the date from datetimepicker and hits postmelater. Now, the ajax code for that looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#myform').validate({// initialize the plugin
    errorElement: 'div',
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        slogan: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
        },
        terms: {
            required: true,
            maxlength: 2
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
        alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
        var mail = $("#email").val(); //mg
        var text = $("#textarea").val();
        var date = 0;
        var stand = 1;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'savedatanow.php'
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                mail: mail,
                text: text,
                date: date,
                stand: stand

            },
            success: function(response)
            {

                alert(response);
            }
        });

    }
});
$('#myform').find('input, textarea').on('change', function () {
    var btn = $('#myform').find('input[type=submit]');
    if ($('#myform').valid()) {
        btn.removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        btn.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
});
```

There's a validation process attached to the fields and so far - only support for the first button. How can I add a support for 2nd button, and in case when user clicks it - also pass the datetime attribute to ajax? Can I distinguish them somehow in Ajax? Thanks!

Comment: Does this question help? I had a similiar issue; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30351028/determining-button-used-to-submit-with-php

Comment: yes, at least a little :) I just still don't know exactly how to include that in my code... could you be so kind and help me with introducing that in my existing code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here depends on functionality of validation plugin, when it reacts, but likely you can try to add onclick to buttons which sets some hidden variable, indicating which button was pushed. Like this:

```
<input type="submit" id="sendfeedback" onclick="this.form.clickedbtn.value=1" value="now" disabled/>

<input type="submit" id="postmelater" value="send" onclick="this.form.clickedbtn.value=2" disabled/>
```

and also add hidden input to the form like this

```
<input type="hidden" id="clickedbtn" name="clickedbtn">
```

Than in the handler add

```
var clickedbtn = $("#textarea").val();

...

clickedbtn: clickedbtn,
```

so form will look like this:

```
<form class="center" id="myform">
<input type="hidden" id="clickedbtn" name="clickedbtn">
<p>
    <input id="email" name="email" type="email" class="textox email" title="" placeholder="your@email.com" required>
</p>
    <textarea name="slogan" id="textarea" maxlength="140" style="resize:none" class="textoxarea" title="Please enter at least 5 characters" placeholder="Placeholder" ></textarea>
```

I accept terms

```
</p>
<input type="submit" id="sendfeedback" value="now" onclick="this.form.clickedbtn.value=1" disabled/>
<input id="datetimepicker" type="text" readonly="readonly">
    <input type="submit" onclick="this.form.clickedbtn.value=2" id="postmelater" value="send" disabled/>
</form>
```

And handler will look like this:

```
submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
    alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
    var mail = $("#email").val(); //mg
    var text = $("#textarea").val();
    var date = 0;
    var stand = 1;
    var clickedbtn = $("#textarea").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'savedatanow.php'
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            mail: mail,
            text: text,
            date: date,
            clickedbtn: clickedbtn,
            stand: stand

        },
        success: function(response)
        {

            alert(response);
        }
    });

}
```

After that in php script you can check

```
if ($_POST["clickedbtn"]==1) {
  send now code
} else {
  other code
}
```

Comment: thank you, just one thing - why do we refer to textarea here `var clickedbtn = $("#textarea").val();` ?

Comment: Mistyped. There have to be var clickedbtn = $("#clickedbtn").val();

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$('#myform').find('input, textarea').on('change', function () {
    var btn = $('#myform').find('input[type=submit]');
    if ($('#myform').valid()) {
        btn.removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        btn.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

to

```
$('#myform').find('input, textarea').on('change', function () {
    var sendfeedbackbtn = $('#sendfeedback');
    var postmelaterbtn = $('#postmelater');
    var datepicker = $('#datetimepicker');
    if ($('#myform').valid()) {
        sendfeedbackbtn.removeAttr('disabled');
        datepicker.removeAttr('readonly');
        if (isTimeValid()) {
           postmelaterbtn.removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    } else {
        datepicker.attr('readonly', 'readonly');
        sendfeedbackbtn.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        postmelaterbtn.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

So it enables the `sendfeedback` and the timestamp input area. And if not valid, all `button` and `timestamp` area will be disabled.
Then add

```
$('#myform').find('#datetimepicker').on('change', function () {
    var postmelaterbtn = $('#postmelater');
    var datepicker = $('#datetimepicker');
    // Need to implement isTimeValid method.
    if ($('#myform').valid() && isTimeValid()) {
        postmelaterbtn.removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        postmelaterbtn.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

So when the timestamp area is changed, check if its valid (need implement isTimeValid), and decide whether to make `postmelater` able to clicked or not.

And your submit handler should be:

```
submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
        alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
        var mail = $("#email").val(); //mg
        var text = $("#textarea").val();
        // Decide to send a timestamp data or not.
        var timestamp = $('#datetimepicker').attr('readonly') ? null : $('#datetimepicker').val();
        var date = 0;
        var stand = 1;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'savedatanow.php',
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                mail: mail,
                text: text,
                date: date,
                stand: stand
                // So this value will be null or whatever your input
                timestamp: timestamp
            },
            success: function(response)
            {

                alert(response);
            }
        });

    }
```

And you can decide `PHP` side's behavior on whether the given `timestamp` is a `null` value or not.

As you give all these `inputs` an `id`, I directly use its `id` selector to get them, but you can still change to other selector at wish.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `js`/`php` to set the default value of your date field to be current date. That way you would only need one `submit` button:

```
<input type="date" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d")?>">
```

or

```
<input type="date" id="datefield">
<script>
  document.getElementById("datefield").value = new Date().getFullYear()+"-"+("0"+(new Date().getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)+"-"+("0" + new Date().getDate()).slice(-2);
</script>
```

---

But if you absolutely want to have two buttons, you could do:

```
<input type="button" onClick="firstButton()">
<input type="button" onClick="secondButton()">
```

and

```
function firstButton(){
    //do what you need to
    document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].submit();
}
```

...and same for button two.